# How to set a specific script on NoScript?

Tags: script, noscript

I'm on a page where you can't copy anything, and if I turn off scripting permissions, it lets me copy, but if I don't, it doesn't, and I can't do anything else that I need to do.  Is there any way to only block the scrip that is blocking my copying?

Answer (score 1):

No, NoScript works at the (sub)domain level, so unless the code you want to run is hosted on a different sub-domain than the code you do not want to run, it cannot help you. You might be able to bypass the undesired code using a userscript via GreaseMonkey.